# How do I output a comma separated field as separate items efficiently?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a field in a mongodb collection with comma separated values such as...

```
{tags: 'Family friendly, Clean &amp; tidy, Close to town centre, Good location, Friendly staff, Good breakfast, Book my next stay'}
```

In my template files I would normally call something like {{tags}}, or if I had an array might be able to use {{#each tags}} etc...

What I want to do though is wrap each item in additional HTML such as a span.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Here's my helper function so far, it creates an array but I don't know the best way to use this in my HTML page so I can wrap spans around each item.

```
Template.tags.helpers({
  getTags: function(input) {
    var tagArray = [];
    tagArray = input.split(',');
    return tagArray;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tags.split( ", " )`, but storing the tags in an array is more flexible and makes more sense.

Comment: I've created a helper which creates an array using tags.split(','), but I'm unsure how I can use this my HTML page. I'm calling my helper via {{getTags reviewTags}}

Answer (score 1):

Using my helper *getTags* I could iterate over the array it returned with the following code:

```
{{#each getTags reviewTags}}
  <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

The *this* keyword can be used to output each item.

I'm not sure if this is **the** most efficient way, but it keeps the HTML where I want it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just store the tags in an array?

Comment: Only that they are submitted to the DB from the value of a text input. so I suppose I would either have to convert them to an array at that point, or the point I am doing it currently.

Comment: Ah yes, definitely convert them with `.split()` before putting them into the DB. For one, it means that you only have to worry about conversion from string to array once.